# How can I reformat a list of items from lua to kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, lua

I am working on a project that originally started in Lua and I want to update it to Kotlin.

I have about 5000 questions/answers that look like:

```lua
['Question'][1] = "'7x' was used to refer to the secret ingredient of what drink";
['Answers'][1] = {"coca cola"};
['Question'][2] = "'And the big wheel keep on turning neon burning up above and I'm just high on the world come on and take the low ride with me girl on the.....' What's the Dire Straits song title?";
['Answers'][2] = {"tunnel of love"};
```

I want to change the format of these without manually going through all 5000, so that they look like:

```kotlin
val que1 = Question(
   1, "'7x' was used to refer to the secret ingredient of what drink",
"coca cola"
        )
val que2 = Question(
            2, "'And the big wheel keep on turning neon burning up above and I'm just high on the world come on and take the low ride with me girl on the.....' What's the Dire Straits song title?",
"tunnel of love"
        )
```

Please help me figure out how to reformat these questions/answers. Thanks.

Comment: You could write a script in any programming language to parse and modify your text. I suggest picking your favorite language and looking up how to do it in that language. However, I would not recommend writing Kotlin code with 5000 properties. Those items should go into Lists or Maps, depending on how you’re using them.

Comment: How is this question related to Lua?

Answer (score 0):

You can write a script like this to get the desired output.

Step 1: Create `input.txt` and paste your lua code here which you want to translate

```lua
['Question'][1] = "'7x' was used to refer to the secret ingredient of what drink";
['Answers'][1] = {"coca cola"};
['Question'][2] = "'And the big wheel keep on turning neon burning up above and I'm just high on the world come on and take the low ride with me girl on the.....' What's the Dire Straits song title?";
['Answers'][2] = {"tunnel of love"};
```

Step 2: Create an empty file named `output.txt`. This file will consist of converted code.

Step 3: Run this `main` function. You might need to modify file path base on your directory structure. Note: This code is written in `Kotlin`.

```kotlin
fun main() {
    val input = File("src/main/kotlin", "input.txt").readLines()
    val outputWriter = File("src/main/kotlin", "output.txt").printWriter()

    val lines = input.windowed(2, 2)
    val questions = mutableListOf<String>()
    lines.forEachIndexed { index, str ->
        val que = str[0].split("\"")[1]
        val ans = str[1].split("\"")[1]

        val question = "val que${index + 1} = Question(${index + 1}, \"$que\", \"$ans\")"
        println(question)
        questions.add(question)

    }

    outputWriter.use { out->
        questions.forEach {
            out.println(it)
        }
    }
}
```

After running the script you will get the desired output in `output.txt`. Alternatively, you can also get this from the console.